# c# - Entity Framework Hyperlink on Field

Tags: c#

Instructor wants us to create a database using asp.net entity framework with a searchable, filtered, table which has fields like titles and price- which I got going.  However, the we also need to have a hyperlink to a detailed page when they click on the field title of each particular item.  How would I go about creating links to each item?  So I have about 10 items with different titles, I want to click on each title and that takes me to a particular page, like Item1.chtml.

**index.chtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model IEnumerable<DVDStore.Data.Models.DVD>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p></p>



    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DVD", FormMethod.Get))
    {
<p>

    Title: @Html.TextBox("FilterText") <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>



    }
    </p>


    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>

                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

**controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DVDStore.Access.Methods;

namespace DVDStore.WEB.Controllers
{
    public class DVDController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(string filterText)
        {            
            FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();
            IEnumerable<Data.Models.DVD> dvds = findDVDs.FindAllDVD("", "");
            var Results = dvds;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterText) == false)
            {
                //search on a specific term
                Results = dvds.Where(d => d.Title.ToLower().Contains(filterText)) ;
            }

            return View(Results.ToList());


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `Html.Action` method, which creates hyperlinks.

You can pass data to that method, for example, action method, controller, query string and so on.

Comment: i'll look into but i'm not sure how i would go about inserting a hyperlink though from what i've seen